# Sygic issue in calculating the route

Tags: swift, maps, sygic, sygic-mobile-sdk

I have a problem when I tried to add a route in my **Sygic offline map view**. In the debugger, I got this message " Routing interface: Asking for unknown transport mode." this the code that I wrote:

```
   class SygicMapViewController: UIViewController, SYNavigationDelegate,SYRoutingDelegate,SYMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    let mapView = SYMapView()
    let routing = SYRouting()
    var  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func setupMapView(){
        let tiltFor2D: SYAngle = 0
        mapView.tilt = tiltFor2D
        mapView.zoom = 12
        mapView.rotation = 180
        mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height:self.view.frame.size.height+20)
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.renderEnabled = true
    }
    func addMarkers(){

    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: SYMapView, didFinishInitialization success: Bool) {
        setupMapView()
        SYNavigation.shared().delegate = self
        routing.delegate = self
        let startPoint = SYGeoCoordinate(latitude: 37.270665, longitude:  9.873921)
        let endPoint = SYGeoCoordinate(latitude: 37.242681, longitude: 9.911932)
        computeRoute(from: startPoint!, to: endPoint!)
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func computeRoute(from fromCoordinate: SYGeoCoordinate, to toCoordinate:
        SYGeoCoordinate) {
        let startWaypoint = SYWaypoint(position: fromCoordinate, type: .start, name: "Begin")
        let endWaypoint = SYWaypoint(position: toCoordinate, type: .end, name: "End")
        let routingOptions = SYRoutingOptions()
        routingOptions.transportMode = .unknown// For other options see SYTransportMode
        routingOptions.routingType = .economic// For other options see SYRoutingType
        routing.computeRoute(startWaypoint, to: endWaypoint, via: nil, with: routingOptions)
    }

    func routing(_ routing: SYRouting, computingFailedWithError error: SYRoutingError) {
        print(error)
    }

    func routing(_ routing: SYRouting, didComputePrimaryRoute route: SYRoute?) {
        SYNavigation.shared().start(with: route)
        // You might want to put it also on the map
        let mapRoute = SYMapRoute(route: route!, type: .primary)
        mapView.add(mapRoute)
        mapView.cameraMovementMode = .followGpsPosition
    }
}
```

I correct the issue by selecting the local routing variable in the computeRoute method and I made some changes to fire the computeRoute method after the mapview Intialization

Answer (score 1):

I actually see two issues with your code.

1. In `func computeRoute(from fromCoordinate: SYGeoCoordinate, to
   toCoordinate: SYGeoCoordinate)` you define local variable `routing`
   which hides instance variable. This causes the routing to be
   deallocated before it can compute any route. So just remove that
   `let routing = SYRouting()` from that method and use instance
   `routing` variable.
2. The other one can also be an issue and cause problems. You start
   routing in `viewDidLoad` before map is initialised. Then if the
   routing is faster you will be adding `SYRoute` object to map and
   that would probably crash. I know this is just some quick setup, but
   to avoid any issues move that call to `computeRoute` at least to
   `mapView(_, didFinishInitialization)` method.

Comment: thank you I resolve the issue by removing local variable routing that block delegate fire

Comment: but I had an issue to fire the navigation now and detect my position in the route that I draw have you an  idea about this please ? I made some changes in the code that you can check with me what is wrong

Comment: if you mean that you want the SDK to start updating position based on your GPS, you need to use `SYPositioning` this class handles stuff related to that... At least you need to call `SYPositioning.shared().startUpdatingPosition()` after SDK is initialised, this will handle all the permissions and other stuff you need.